# How do Machine Learning frameworks save their training models?

Tags: c#, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a project that I'm currently implementing on CNN in C# from scratch with Numpy.NET without frameworks involved. I am curious or stuck on what or how do you save models you trained? Kind of like the pickle files from python but I am looking at saving into ONNX but I don't have an ounce of idea how to do it manually from my own train and test functions.

I tried searching on how to save machine learning models in google but all the results majorly shows on how to do it on python, which uses pickle. I have a hunch that I am saving the data as a binary file? but I can't visualize the data inside the training models which I am trying to replicate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onnx format specification can be found [here](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/IR.md). It is based on protocol buffers, and the repo should contain .proto / .proto3 files. These can be used with libraries to generate classes you can populate and serialize. The two libraries I know of are [google protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial). and [Protobuf .net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net). I have only used the later. Refer to the respective documentation on how to generate classes from the proto-files.

If you do not need any interoperability you could just create your own format, this might be easier if the main goal is just to learn. I would still consider using the same protobuf approach as onnx, since this is a fairly easy way to save all kinds of data.